# Is it possible to use a deep learning library (Tensorflow, PyTorch, MXNet) to train models for Botframework?

Tags: tensorflow, botframework, pytorch

If I recall correctly, you need to train models on LUIS.ai to use with Botframework-Python. I want to train my own models with my own architecture using a deep learning library. So the question is, is it possible to train models using DL frameworks?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to incorporate deep-learning models with LUIS, or are you asking if it's possible to incorporate alternative machine learning architecture with the Bot Framework?

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to incorporate a custom machine learning architecture in Bot Framework

Comment: I presume it is possible and I can look into it further. Can you provide some more information about what you've tried so far?

Comment: I came across this framework called [Plato Research Dialogue System](https://github.com/uber-research/plato-research-dialogue-system) by Uber on Github. It seems that it may fulfill my needs.

Comment: Can you explain more about what your needs are that it's fulfilling? Are you looking at Plato as an alternative to the Bot Framework, or are you asking how to integrate Plato with the Bot Framework?

Comment: I am performing NLP research for chatbots. As such, I want to find a platform that is suitable for training a chatbot. Although there are numerous platforms already available (ParlAI, DeepPavlop), none of them seem to fit my criteria (no Windows support or no online learning ability). The closest to finding a platform for training my chatbot was Botframework, but it seems to be built for production using Microsoft's internal tools.

Comment: Does [Conversation Learner](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-conversation-learner) sound like the kind of training you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need for my research!

Comment: Was that the answer you're looking for or would you still like an example of how to incorporate a deep learning library like TensorFlow with the Bot Framework?

Comment: I think this is good enough, but I would love to be able to use a DL library with Bot Framework nonetheless.

Comment: @AyazAmin have you checked out the experimental sample in the python repo, [101.corebot-bert-bidar](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/master/samples/experimental/101.corebot-bert-bidaf)?  Demonstrates using open source language models eploying BERT and BiDAF

Comment: I checked it right now. It seems much simpler to use than Conversation Learner. It seems to make use of ONNX, so that is a plus point. Thank you!